# Python Appengine - Pass two entities to jinja template view

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I have a View-Consult page and the request handler is:

```
class ViewConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        consult = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key')).get()
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/view-consult.html')
        template_values = {
        'consult': consult
        }
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

It displays info about the consult. An Assessment is then created with the same ID as the Consult. I then want to display info about consult and assessment on the same page.

I assumed I add in the assessment to the handler similar to the consult:

```
class ViewConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        consult = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key')).get()
        assessment = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key')).get()
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/view-consult.html')
        template_values = {
        'consult': consult,
        'assessment': assessment
        }
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

When I load the view-consult page the Consult properties are rendering as before, but the Assessment properties, eg {{ assessment.assess_notes }} are printing as empty strings (or nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `consult` and the `assessment` share the same key ID, but not the same key and urlsafe string, so you can't use the same method for getting the entity.

You can obtain the `assessment` entity by its key ID - identical for both entities. So I'd re-write the 1st 2 lines of `get()` like this:

```
consult_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key'))
consult = consult_key.get()
# assessment and consult have the same key ID
assessment = Assesment.get_by_id(consult_key.id())
```